# How center div with percentage width on responsive page?

Tags: html, css, center

I have a responsive page which can be resized to fit a desktop, tablet or phone. The phone and tablet css is ok but I have problem with the desktop. The difference is the main div which holds all the content.

For the phone and tablet, the main div width is 100% of the screen but for the desktop it should be fixed at 900px and also centered on the screen.

When I have it centered, the main div won't adjust its height depending on the content in it but it will for the other screen sizes. When I add a float: left; to the main div, it floats to the right and then the height follows the content in it

It's probably a really simple fix but I have tried everything I know and googled without finding the solution.

Thanks guys!

```css
body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 0;
}
#main {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  color: #222222;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
/* Home Big
/*************************/

#home-big {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
#home-big h1 {
  background-color: #1eaccc;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px;
}
/* Home Big Content
/*************************/

.home-big-content {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
/* Home Big Left
/*************************/

.home-big-left {
  background-color: #ffff00;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.home-big-left img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
/* Home Big Right
/*************************/

.home-big-right {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
/* TABLET SIZE
/*****************************************************************************/

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  #main {
    background-color: #00ff00;
    float: left;
    height: initial;
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
  #home-big {
    margin: 0 10px;
    width: initial;
  }
  .home-big-left {
    background-color: #ffff00;
  }
}
/* DESKTOP SIZE
/*****************************************************************************/

@media all and (min-width: 900px) {
  #main {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    float: initial;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
  }
  #home-big {
    margin: 0;
    width: initial;
  }
  .home-big-left {
    background-color: #ffff00;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="main">
    <article id="home-big">
      <h1>Headline</h1>

      <div class="home-big-content">
        <div class="home-big-left">
          Left
        </div>
        <div class="home-big-right">
          Right
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm just trying to imagine your website with 900px fix on my KindleFire (2560px - 65% of viewport wasted) or computer screen (8000px, almost 90% of viewport wasted). When you make website responsive, please consider that age of 1024x768 displays is long gone. Responsive means to fit **any** display.

Comment: I'm going to disagree with the statement, _"Responsive means to fit **any** display."_ If you have a display that is 6,000px wide, should by website also be 6,000px wide? Just about every responsive web design has an upper limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you float stuff, you have to clear it or use `overflow: hidden`

Try:

```
.clearfix:after { 
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Apply clearfix class to all containers that contain floated elements, or use `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: The overflow: hidden; on the #main worked! But why? I thought it would just clip a div that is too big for the container?

Comment: It establishes a new block formatting context. It's not very nice to use `overflow: hidden;` though. Better go with the clearfix.

Comment: I used it on the main div and it also worked fine, so I'll use that then. :) Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the floats that are with your `#main` element. I use the [micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Use as follows:

```html
<section id="main" class="cf"></section>
```

```css
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}    
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```